# How to use Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have used paint editor to create a scheme but I'm not satisfied by the result. So I decided to use Tikz. I haven't found any good tutorial, the ones I'm reading gives the commands without explaining what the signification of the symbols. Here's the scheme I want to do :

[image]

I started like this :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle, draw, text width={3.5cm},  minimum height={6cm}, text centered] (l) {l};
\node[rectangle, draw, text width={3.5cm},  minimum height={6cm}, text centered, below right=0cm and 2cm of l.north east] (r) {r};
\draw[->] (l.center) -- (r.center); % Problem : How to connect the left side of l with the right side of r?
\draw[->] (r.160) -- (l.160);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Can someone guide to do that. For example how to draw rectangles inside another rectangle. Make a list of text above an arrow. And anything that you think that will help to do my scheme.

Is there a good tutorial where I can learn using Tikz. Thanks for the help

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: tikz has a very large documentation with a lots of examples. Look for `pgfmanual.pdf` on your system.

Comment: http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf contains some introductory examples which can be used as a starting point

Comment: Yes, and [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) you find the _minimal introduction_ in pdf, further than the _heavy_ latest version of the manual, which is richest of examples similar to yours. Yo may need \usetikzlibrary{arrows} for thin arrows.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to do it but it's difficult. Could you tell me how to print the 'MEANS' text below the top line. I succeeded to print it but above the line by using this code :`\node[fit=(inOut)(api)(logiciel), draw, label={[inner sep=0pt,minimum height=2ex]above:MEANS}] (rside) {};`

Comment: Personally, I would draw all the inside parts first, then fit the outer rectangle as needed (possibly using layers).

Comment: @user230137 I would not use `label`. Instead, draw only the outer frame as you did, and then `\node[below] at (rside.north) {MEANS};`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an attempt, hoping it will help. `b` style means horizontal box, `c` style is for vertical box, `ar` is line style, and `myarrow` style is for the two-colored arrow.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning,fit,calc,}
\tikzset{
b/.style={draw, rectangle, rounded corners=2ex,minimum height=0.5in, minimum width=2in,align=center},
c/.style={draw, rectangle, rounded corners=2ex, minimum height=0.5in, minimum  width=2in,align=center, rotate=-90},
ar/.style={rounded corners=2ex,->,>=latex },  
myarrow/.style args={#1 colored by #2 and #3}{
    -stealth,line width=#1,#2,postaction={draw,-stealth,#3,line width=(#1)/3,
    shorten <=(#1)/3,shorten >=2*(#1)/3}, 
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \node (block1) [b] {Application InOut};
    \node (block2) [b,below= 4cm of block1] {Logical de calcul \\ d'indicateurs};
    \node (block3)[c, right=2cm of block1]  {API Java \\ \color{red} (requetes, recuperation \\ \color{red}desresulats)};
% connections within block A
\draw[ar] ([xshift=-1cm]block1.south) --++ (0,-2cm) -- ++(1,0) -- ([xshift=-1cm]block2.north);
\draw[ar] ([xshift= 1cm]block1.south) |- ([yshift=1cm]block3.south);
\draw[ar] ([yshift=-1cm]block3.south) -| (block1.south);
\node (block4) [c,right=9cm of block1] {Services Web \\ \color{red} (REST)};
\node (block5) [c, right= 11cm of block1] {MicMac \\ \color{red} (simulation)};
% connections within block B
\draw[ar] ([yshift=0.5cm]block4.north)  -- ([yshift=0.5cm]block5.south);
\draw[ar] ([yshift=-0.5cm]block5.south) -- ([yshift=-0.5cm]block4.north);
% connection between blocks A and B
\draw[ar] ([yshift=0.5cm]block3.north)  -- node[above]{\parbox[t]{3cm}{- Choix du scenario\\
- Fichiers meteo}} ([yshift=0.5cm]block4.south);
\draw[ar] ([yshift=-0.5cm]block4.south) --node[below]{\parbox[t]{3cm}{- Apport d'zaote \\
- Apport de pesticide}} ([yshift=-0.5cm]block3.north);
\node(n1)[draw,fill opacity=0.2,fill=blue, fit=(block1)(block2)(block3),inner sep=3em,
label={[inner sep=0pt,yshift=-0.5cm]above:MEANS}
]{};
\node(n2)[draw,fill opacity=0.2,fill=blue, fit=(block4)(block5),inner sep=3em,
label={[inner sep=0pt,yshift=-0.5cm]above:RECORD}
]{};
\draw[myarrow=10pt colored by blue!50!white and white] (block2.south) --node[right,xshift= 0.2cm](){\color{red} (Indicateurs)} ++(0,-1.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have got a problem when I tried to include this sheme into a beamer presentation. I posted a question here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172384/whats-the-better-way-to-include-a-tikz-sheme-into-a-beamer-presentation.